# Por que me marca error en estas dos lineas de codigo

Tags: php, html5, visual-studio

Al ejecutar este trozo de código:

```
<?php
session_start();
$usuario = $_POST['login'];
$password = sha1($_POST['password']);

include "../../../clases/Usuarios.php";
$Usuarios = new Usuarios();

echo $Usuarios->loginUsuario($usuario, $password);
```

Obtengo los siguientes errores.

```
Warning: Undefined array key "login" in C:\xampp\htdocs\sitio\public\procesos\usuarios\login\loginUsuario.php on line 3

Warning: Undefined array key "password" in C:\xampp\htdocs\sitio\public\procesos\usuarios\login\loginUsuario.php on line 4
```

¿Por qué marca error en esas dos líneas?

---

```
<?php
session_start();
$usuario = $_POST['login'];
$password = sha1($_POST['password']);

include "../../../clases/Usuarios.php";
$Usuarios = new Usuarios();

echo $Usuarios->loginUsuario($usuario, $password);
```

?>

Comment: al parecer ni "login" ni "password" existen como claves del array ( `GET[]` `POST[]` `REQUEST[]` `SESSION[]` ?) al momento de accederlas

Comment: Agrega el código que te está dando error por favor

Comment: Hola Erika, recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces quieras. Tu código hace parte de tu pregunta, asi que agregarla como respuesta no tiene sentido en este caso. Te invito a eliminar esa respuesta, [edit] tu pregunta y agregar el código relevante ahi. A propósito, sería util que mostraras cual es el código que hace el llamado post y como está enviando esos parámetros al servidor. Saludos

Comment: Bienvenida a StackOverflow, te invito a hacer el [tour]. Moví el código que dejaste en la respuesta a la pregunta. En el futuro no dejes respuestas si no estás realmente respondiendo a la pregunta. StackOverflow no es un foro, por eso es importante que hagas el tour. Por favor elimina la no/respuesta que publicaste. Yo la he reportado, a ver si un moderador diamantado lo hace también. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

**Undefined array key** - El error como tal te avisa que tus llaves no están definidas, por lo que no las puede obtener de ningun modo.

El problema se basa desde donde las están enviando, asi que revisa ese archivo igual.

Pero ahora, como controlamos el error ?? Pues es simple, podemos validar las variables que queremos obtener.

```
if (isset($_POST['login']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    //...nuestro codigo aca
}else{
    echo "Las variables no se han llegado al archivo";
}
```

Asi mientras vas probando el envio de datos, verificas que esta mal.
Incluso puedes separar ambas variables al validarlas, y revisar una por una, luego lo cambias.